# How to turn on word wrapping of icon names in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, icons, desktop-icons

I just upgraded from 18 to 20.04lts, and the file names on the desktop icons are all truncated with ellipsis.

This is what i've tried:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep ellipsis
org.nemo.icon-view text-ellipsis-limit ['3']
org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view text-ellipsis-limit ['3']
org.nemo.desktop text-ellipsis-limit 2
$ gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.desktop text-ellipsis-limit
No such schema “org.gnome.nautilus.desktop”
```

So all limits seem to be at their default of 2 or 3 lines. The icon-view entries ask for a delimited string instead of a number.
But all my desktop icons have their name truncated with ellipsis on the first line.
Also tried changing the settings to 0 (and restarting with Alt+F2 r), but no change.

Is there a different setting somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized it was due to the icon height limit, set up on

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/prefs.js
```

After raising the height there was enough room for the extra lines to show up.